# Fetch the records based on the topics

Tags: visualforce, soql

Can anyone tell me how to fetch the records based on the topic name..
Like I have 20 contacts ..10 contacts are associated with the topic name **test1** and others are **test2**

Wanna fetch the records associated with the topic name **test1**
Please Help!

Comment: It will be great if you elaborate question a bit, You want SOQL Query for fetching such records ?

Comment: @NileshMendhe: Yep.. I need a soql query for fetching those records

Comment: You need to retrieve records which are topic field set to `test1` or `test2` and then do some work based on the topic is it?

Comment: NileshMendhe : Hy @Nilesh Mendhe: I don't want to create any custom field for that object. Just add the topic to that record ..                                   like                https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=basics_add_topics_records.htm&language=en_US

Comment: @NileshMendhe : please help

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have created a Custom Field on Contact for saving your Topic Names, Lets take its API as 
**topic_name__c**

then your possible SOQL query will be -

**select id,Name from Contact where topic_name__c='test1'**

See how  I have used it to get my records in List -

```
List<Contact> lstContact = new List<Contact>();

    lstContact=[select id,Name from Contact where topic_name__c='test1'];   
    //here you got you got your records of topic=test1 in List lstContact, now use for loop to access them - like

    for(Contact objContact:lstContact){
        /* you have got each record in **objContact** who's having topic_name=test1, you access fields as per your requirement*/  
      System.Debug('---Name---'+objContact.Name);
    }
```

Comment: Hy @Nilesh Mendhe: I don't want to create any custom field for that object.       Just add the topic to that record .. like https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=basics_add_topics_records.htm&language=en_US

Comment: hey are you there?

Comment: @user3332076 : Ohh, I didn't got enough time to search for the answer, but I'll get back on this, ASAP.